# What are the different types of Mulch?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I've managed to get to the berry farm, and so I'm attempting to greenify my thumb.  The little girl says I can make Mulch by putting three berries in the composter, so I've got that figured out.  But she doesn't tell me what types of Mulch there are.  So far, I've managed to get both Surprise Mulch, and Boost Mulch.

So my question is three-fold:

- What kinds of Mulch are there?
- What effects do they have?
- What berries do I use to acquire it?

Answer (score 6):

There are 7 types of Mulch, 6 inherited from previous generations with 1 new type.

- Boost Mulch - Increases number of Berries harvested if you water carefully
- Damp Mulch - Soil dries more slowly but Berry growth rate is reduced
- Gooey Mulch - Increases chance a Berry tree will grow if the previous tree withered
- Growth Mulch - Increase Berry growth rate but soil dries more quickly
- Rich Mulch - Increases number of Berries harvested regardless of watering
- Stable Mulch - Berries stay on the tree for longer
- Surprise Mulch - Allows mutations based on nearby Berry trees

Currently, there is little more than anecdotal evidence for which Berries create which Mulch. I personally have used **Oran, Oran, Oran** to get Surprise Mulch and **Sitrus, Iapapa, Aguav** to make Rich Mulch.

Surprise Mulch is a newcomer to the Mulch scene. Depending on what Berry trees are nearby, you might see a completely different type of Berry on your tree. Usually only one Berry is converted to the different type so don't worry about losing that one Berry you have when you plant it on Surprise Mulch.

Currrent known mutations:

- Aspear + Leppa = Hondew
- Chesto + Persim = Kelpsy
- Iapapa + Mago = Pomeg
- Oran + Pecha = Qualot
- Sitrus + Lum = Tamato
- Hondew + Yache = Petaya

Comment: Are mutations new to the series?

Comment: Another combination for Rich mulch is **Oran, Iapapa,** and **Pecha**.

Comment: I think any 3 of the same berry creates Surprise Mulch. I've tried Oran, Pecha, Aspear and Iapapa so far.

Comment: And it is probably worth noting that Mulch is worth 100 Poke a piece (and you get them 3 at a time) while Berries are all worth 10.

Comment: Honeydew berries are made by crossing Aspear berries and Leppa berries.

Comment: Iapapa, Agauv, and Mago also make Rich mulch. It's easiest because they're all right in a row in the bag.